# How to check container uptime from inside docker container (without docker installed in container)?

Tags: docker

How to check container uptime from inside docker container without having docker installed in the container?

- `uptime` gives the uptime of the host machine
- `last reboot` tries to read `/var/log/wtmp` and outputs nothing
- `docker ps` would give the uptime, but I don't have it inside the container

Comment: In your application code, just record the time when the process started, if you need to know that.  Possibly your language runtime already keeps track of it.  The container only runs a single process; "container uptime" isn't really a concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first process start time could be used as container start time:

```
/var/app # stat /proc/1
File: /proc/1
Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: 91h/145d    Inode: 19102       Links: 9
Access: (0555/dr-xr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-05-08 13:08:14.000000000
Modify: 2023-05-08 13:08:14.000000000
Change: 2023-05-08 13:08:14.000000000
```